# A render in Blender Internal looks like a choppy checkerboard

Tags: rendering, blender-internal-render-engine

I have a mesh that looks fine when I preview it in the viewport via Shift+Z.
[image: (desired look)]
Once I render it, everything has this choppy checkerboard-ish quality to it.
[image: (the render)]
[image: (the choppy checkerboard up-close)]
How do I fix this problem so the render looks like the rendered viewport preview?

Here's the .blend: 
[image]

Comment: probably a ton of coplanar surfaces z-fighting. google the term z-fighting.

Comment: is there a way to change the size of those individual tiles in the render?

Comment: I think this has something to do with the weird value you have stored in the far clipping box in the Camera properties tab.. 10.000.000 is kind of pushing the limits... but will produce an ok image, your value (99999997952.0) is borderline and i'd expect dodgy renders.

Comment: I lowered it to 350000 and it works now! Thank you

Answer (score 5, accepted):

As suggested by [zeffi](https://blender.stackexchange.com/users/47/zeffii) in comments there is a problem in z calculations.

This is probably due to the high values in camera's [frustum](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Viewing_frustum) which leads Blender to make errors.

Lowering the value of clipping plane to the minumum necessary to include all the geometry seems to solve the problem.

[image]